# Attribute error in DictVectorizer in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying the following code in Python scikit learn.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
onehot_encoder = DictVectorizer()
instances = [{'city': 'New York'}, {'city', 'Boston'}, {'city', 'London'}]
onehot_encoder.fit_transform(instances)
```

However, I get the following error:

> 'set' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Could you help me in understanding what this error is about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few typos here:

```
instances = [{'city': 'New York'}, {'city','Boston'},{'city','London'}]
#                                         ^                 ^
```

That is why you created `set` objects, not `dict`. Replace comma with colon and this should work.